# How to convert the MongoDB object id to a Java Date or Instant using Java

Tags: java, mongodb

The MongoDB ObjectID contains an embedded timestamp of its creation time. How can you extract this timestamp with plain Java without using classes of a driver library?

MongoDB creates object id's that typically look like:

```
5b86bd41840a1be5a55c7022
598af6efe4b09fc2332cf16a
598ad932e4b0f0f169b42d5f
```

The extraction target can be either a `long`, `java.util.Date` or a `java.time.Instant`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on this [page](https://steveridout.github.io/mongo-object-time/) you could convert with these static methods the MongoDB ObjectID to a timestamp, `java.util.Date` or a `java.time.Instant` object:

```
public static Instant convertToInstantFrom(String objectId) {
    return convertToDateFrom(objectId).toInstant();
}

public static Date convertToDateFrom(String objectId) {
    return new Date(convertToTimestampFrom(objectId));
}

public static long convertToTimestampFrom(String objectId) {
    return Long.parseLong(objectId.substring(0, 8), 16) * 1000;
}
```

If you run the following code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    Stream.of("5b86bd41840a1be5a55c7022", "598af6efe4b09fc2332cf16a", "598ad932e4b0f0f169b42d5f")
            .map(SimpleTests::convertToInstantFrom).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

You will see this result on the console:

```
2018-08-29T15:35:29Z
2017-08-09T11:50:07Z
2017-08-09T09:43:14Z
```

Comment: Thansk gil, its a good solution, may you suggest let say we do instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC); after that and say we get instant value like 2021-07-15T05:27:00Z, it will reduce to 2021-07-15T05:27Z, 
last zero's removed. Is there any way, we could keep the zero and we want to OffsetDateTime. Thanks